# Can't order my header divs based on screen size?

Tags: html, css

I have a header with three columns: menu, center and right column with logo.

I call bootstrap 3.4.1 from my index.php

I have this (simplified) code:

```
<header id="header" class="container-fluid " style="background-image: url('<?= $header_banner ?>');">
     <div class="row h-100 justify-content-xs-right"> 
        <div id="left-menu" class="hidden-xs col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left-menu" />
        </div>
        <?= file_get_contents(__DIR__ ."/images/menu.svg"); ?>

        <div id="center" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-6 justify-content-end align-items-center">
            <jdoc:include type="component" />
        </div>
        
        <div id="right-column" class="hidden-xs sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <div  id="logo" style="background-image: url('<?= $header_logo ?>');">
              <a title="Terug naar Startpagina" class="fill-full-div" href="/?stay"> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

In CSS i defined the order:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {

/* Safari 6.1+ */
div#left-menu   {-webkit-order: 1;}
div#center  {-webkit-order: 3;}
div#right-column {-webkit-order: 2;
}

/* Standard syntax */
div#left-menu  {order: 1;}
div#center  {order: 3;}
div#right-column {order: 2;}

div#right-column
{
  Position: relative!important;
  right:0;
}

}
```

See: https://ontwikkel.go4people.nl

What I want is that the right column with the logo moves to the top when a screen size is less than 992px.

Lay-out I want is two columns like:

left side: menu
right side: top -> logo
below the logo the main content

Currently all functions on xs (<576 px) screens and large (>992px) screens, but small en medium screens don't stack the center and right column next to the menu, they all appear on the

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to use `Css` for this, Bootstrap have built in classes `order` for changing columns on different sizes.

You can learn from official [document of Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

I have added some background color and text for you to understand what is happening.

If i am understanding you clearly,  when you resize the screen you want Logo image get to the top while menu on the left side and content div on below the logo image to the right.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header id="header" class="container" style="background-image: url('<?= $header_banner ?>');">
    <div class="row justify-content-end align-items-start justify-content-xs-right ">
      <div style="background-color: teal;" id="left-menu" class=" hidden-xs col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left-menu" />menu
      </div>
      <?= file_get_contents(__DIR__ ."/images/menu.svg"); ?>

      <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-9">
        <div class="row">
          <div style="background-color: yellow;" id="center"
            class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6  order-lg-6 order-2 justify-content-end align-items-center">
            <jdoc:include type="component" />Content
          </div>
          <div id="right-column" style="background-color: red;" class="hidden-xs col-sm-12 col-lg-6 order-lg-12 order-1 ">
            <div id="logo" style="background-image: url('<?= $header_logo ?>');">
              <a title="Terug naar Startpagina" class="fill-full-div" href="/?stay">LOGO Image</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Almost ;-) Thank you! What I would like is the menu colum on the left and the logo and content split in two rows on the right. Couldn't find that in the bootstrap doc... I adjusted your code to do so, but now still the content part comes in a new row, when screen width is medium

Comment: Updated the answer, let me know if something else is needed!

Comment: That's it! Thank you soo much. I was strugging with the extra row...